# Backup HDD directly to new one (PS4 HDD upgrade)

Tags: ps4

I have a PS4 with 500gb HDD and I've purchased a new 1TB HDD to upgrade the capacity.

According to the official Sony guide, If I want to backup everything (users, saves and installed games) I'd have to find an external storage big enough (~400GB as the disk is almost full) to witch I backup and the restore from when the new HDD is installed.

So the path would be OLD HDD->External Drive->New HDD.

My question - is there a way to skip the external drive and copy the data directly to the new hdd. For example plugging the to HDDs to a PC/MAC and running some sort of copy command.

Answer (score -1):

Using a cloning software you should be able to do it.
Just attach old and new disk to your pc, and then use a software like EaseUS to clone the old disk into the new one.

https://www.easeus.com/partition-manager-guide/partition-copy.html

Just make sure that you copy every partition from the old disk or it might not work